# What happens to Colossus' injuries in Deadpool 2?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

During the final confrontation in ***Deadpool* 2**, Deadpool and Cable are trying to save Firefist while

> Colossus holds off the Juggernaut by taking a leaf out of Deadpool's book and *fighting dirty*.

During this scene I saw that **Colossus** (in his metal form) gets his forehead smashed and dented by

> the Juggernaut.

So, what kind of injury would his dented forehead transform into if (and when) he returns to his normal human form?

Comment: ... he has a normal human form?

Comment: He has a normal human form in the comics, however it is unclear if this is the case in Deadpool, as there are many scenes at the x-mansion where in the comics he would have probably been drawn in his human form, but in the film we only see his metal form. It may be that this is his only form in the film.

Comment: Normally, Magneto is capable of healing him. Not sure about this movie though.

Comment: I agree with what @Jack said. The film version most likely doesn't have a human form anymore (presumably ever since his X-gene expressed itself/got activated). This might change in the future if Marvel Studios decides so, but they would most likely reboot Deadpool and introduce him in the MCU. Let's see.

Comment: Maybe the dent heals up (fills up?) the same way a cut on a human would? When World War Hulk broke Colossus's arms in the comic books, they were heated using a powerful laser just enough to soften them enough to enable straightening them out but not enough to hurt him further. This was possible cause of the expertise of Beast and Professor X. Elixir did the rest of the required healing once he changed into his human form thereafter.